# How to Request and approval system in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a site where I want to show a list of developers on homepage after login along with price/hour for each developer and users has to able to request a developer for their project using request button and fill the form and submit.

From the developer end, the developer which user contacted will be shown the requests he got along with the option to accept or reject and if accepted user and site owner (Admin) has to receive an email.

So I need to know whether there is a plugin or any other thing for this kind of purpose.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That sounds very specific. I doubt you're going to find a plugin that does all that. Either way, this question is off topic for this website and it will likely be closed.

Comment: I just need a similar solution not according to my exact requirement.